# Can my opponent tap lands for mana when I have Sen Triplets on the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have been wracking my brain, trying to come up with interesting ways to use [Piracy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPiracy%5d).

> **UU, Sorcery**
> Until end of turn, you may tap lands you don't control for mana. Spend this mana only to cast spells.

With [Sen Triplets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSen%20Triplets%5d) in play, target opponent can't activate abilities of their permanents:

> This turn, that player can’t cast spells or activate abilities and plays with their hand revealed.

Since tapping a land for mana is an activated ability (activation cost is `T:`), then does this mean that the opponent can't tap their lands?

If so, can I then cast Piracy to use their lands to generate mana in addition to my own, safe in the knowledge that when I pass priority, the opponent won't just tap their lands?

**Bonus**: Further, if I have [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d) in play, then could I do so to multiple opponents in a multiplayer game, by copying the Triplets' triggered ability?

Comment: I removed the "bonus bonus" questions, as they weren't really questions, and strayed too far from the original question. Please consider asking a new question, or several, about those interactions.

Comment: Surprised to see a way to make piracy work post mana burn removal.

Comment: @Andrew seems to me one could use Piracy during the pre-combat main phase, forcing opponents to tap their lands in response, which means no combat tricks from opponents & spells cast during the second main phase are effectively uncounterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, activated mana abilities are regular activated abilities as far as Sen Triplets are concerned, and the chosen opponent(s) can't activate them. You can copy Sen Triplets' ability with Strionic Resonator, and you can choose another opponent with the copy, allowing you to tap lands from all chosen opponents with Piracy.**

> 605.1. Some activated abilities and some triggered abilities are mana abilities, which are subject to special rules.

> 605.3. Activating an activated mana ability follows the rules for activating any other activated ability (see rule 602.2) [..]

As soon as Sen Triplets' ability has resolved, your opponent can't tap lands or activate any other mana ability, and if you cast Piracy later that turn, you can be sure that the opponent can't tap their lands in response. They could, of course, tap their lands and other mana-producing permanents in response to the Sen Triplets ability on the stack, especially if they know you are running Piracy.

Sen Triplets' ability is a triggered ability, so it can be copied by Strionic Resonator, and you can choose another opponent for the copy.

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]”

Comment: Is there a way to tap the lands, before my opponents can tap them?
For example piracy resolves and no one tapped their lands. As the player with priority can i tap all lands, before my opponents are able to tap them?
If i play something like "untap all lands" Am I the first player which can tap all lands?